# Obtaing the position of max in a rollapply type function in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to obtain the position of max value in a group, using rollapply function (zoo package).

What i'm trying to do is create the column "position.of.max.group.of.three":

[image]

What i tried to do:

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
df2$position.of.max.group.of.three = rollapplyr(df2$x, 3, which.max, fill = NA)
```